# frame for "Collection View" will be different at run time Swift3 iOS10 StoryBoard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

When i use a "Collection View" on my project, i get a issue:

Now it is gone it used to be at the orange rect:

[image: Now it is gone it used to be at the orange rect]

Frame for "Collection View" will be different at run time. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have searched the whole internet and found nothing.

So, here is a 'solution', like the screenshot shows, you just check the header then decheck it, the issue will be gone, although, I still don't know what reason cause this happened.

Check the header of uiview content and decheck it:

[image: Check the header of uiview content and decheck it]

Comment: Actually i couldn't understand your problem. what is the problem here?

Comment: You should have put this in community wiki. Really helpful though

Answer (score 0):

It's Interface Builder bug.

Looks similar to [IB problems](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65540)

I'm enjoying this bug in Xcode 8.2.1

It's okey, I do Xcode for 7 years, Interface Builder have a lot of bugs in every single version. It's Apple style, I think. Btw Xcode have a lot of bugs too.

Just ignore.